# :QML word wrap with nbsp on Linux

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, qml, raspbian

I have the following problem:

When I build my application on Windows QML texts do actually wrap correctly with respect to the nbsp character (U+00A0 I think). On my Raspberry Pi with Raspbian however, it seems that the nbsp is ignored and the text is wrapped as if it was just a normal space.

There are several things that may have some importance here:

1. On Windows I have QT 5.4 whereas on the Raspberry Pi there is 5.2
2. I think it may have something to do with encoding. The thing is I remember it worked before I forced the G++ compiler on Pi to take the input files as CP1250 (I added QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -finput-charset=CP1250 to the project file). Well I had to make this tweak because of the diacritics in some of the string literals (otherwise the texts are absolutely broken on raspberry). So as I said I think the word wrap have worked before I changed this compiler switch.

But still, there is not a single problem with the displaying of anything except that the texts happen to be breaked where they shouldn't. Note that there is not any "random" character or something but a regular space. That's absolutely strange as this looks there is no problem with encoding but rather with the word wrapping algorith itslef. But as I said it used to work when it thought the string literals are whatever the default on Linux is (UTF-8 I guess...).

As for the QML Text assignment these strings are taken from C array and assigned to the QML text using QObject::setProperty if that is of any importance...

Also note that I probably cannot change the encoding of my sources to UTF-8 because the file with the strings is shared also for some embedded project that works on the other side of the communication and this one has to be CP1250 because of the IDE.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I have some additional information: If I go through one of the affected string literals on Windows, it is in fact shorter than the same literal compiled on Raspberry, even when the source encoding is set to CP1250. For example the nbsp is encoded in only one byte on Windows (160d), but it is two bytes on Raspberry (194d,160d). That's strange, isn't it? I'd expect that after explaining g++ that the source code is encoded in CP1250, it should encode the literals in the same way? Or maybe not because this is then encoding of the string in the memory which is different by default on both Windows and Linux. But still I don't see where's the problem.

Comment: Qt expects strings in sources to be UTF-8 encoded if you don't explicitly use a conversion function such as `QString::fromLatin1()` or `QString::fromLocal8Bit()` or when using `QTextCodec`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Kevin Krammer,

```
QString::fromLocal8Bit()
```

was the solution.